# Unbable to import function

Tags: python, pycparser

I have tried following

1. when I tried to import the class from the file named plyparser.py of pycparser(https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/pycparser/plyparser.py)
   using the following statement

   ```
   from pycparser.plyparser import Coord
   ```
2. But, I am unable to import function parameterized from plyparser of pycparser using the following statement

   ```
   from  pycparser.plyparser import parameterized
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ImportError: cannot import name parameterized
   ```

   How to resolve this issue.

Comment: `from pycparser import parameterized`

Comment: >>> from pycparser import parameterized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name parameterized

Comment: the same error it is returning

Comment: Can you show the directory tree ?

Comment: /packages/ply/;
/packages/plyj/;
/packages/pyparsing/;
/packages/pycparser/;
/packages/pycparserext/;

Comment: In which directory you are using the `import parameterized` ?

Comment: /packages/pycparser/

Comment: From `packages/pycparser` you can directly import `parameterized` simply using `from pycparser import parameterized`

Comment: Thanks a lot it working now..Thanks one again